# How to replace a value in column when the value to replace match another column value, keep the one that don't match untouched?

Tags: sql

I would like to check if an Item value from table A is matching the Item value from table B, and if yes I want to replace it with the Name of that value and keep the rest of the values untouched.

Thank you!

Manu!
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxTR8.jpg)

I have tried with Case when but unsuccessfully.

Comment: did you explore JOINs?

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 0):

You havn't said which SQL database you are using. Here is an example for SQL server. The syntax varies from one to another.

> ```
> create table A (
> col1 int,
> name varchar(10));
> create table B (
> col1 int,
> name varchar(10));
> insert into A values
> (1,'one a'),
> (2,'two a'),
> (3,'three a');
> insert into B values
> (2,'two b'),
> (3,'three b'),
> (4,'four b');
> GO
> ```

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from A;
> select * from B;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | name   
> ---: | :------
>    1 | one a  
>    2 | two a  
>    3 | three a
>
> col1 | name   
> ---: | :------
>    2 | two b  
>    3 | three b
>    4 | four b
> ```

> ```
> update A
> set A.name = b.name
> from A
> join B 
> on A.col1 = b.col1;
> GO
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from A;
> select * from B;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | name   
> ---: | :------
>    1 | one a  
>    2 | two b  
>    3 | three b
>
> col1 | name   
> ---: | :------
>    2 | two b  
>    3 | three b
>    4 | four b
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7dd98dbad3137adc0cd211b540c04b72)*